# Comparing Datetime to same datetime in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails console,

```
> time1 = DateTime.now
 => Thu, 23 Feb 2017 10:50:27 +0630  
> time2 = "#{time1}"
 => "2017-02-23T10:50:27+06:30" 
> time1 == time2
 => false
```

This is right. Because

```
> time1.class
 => DateTime
> time2.class
 => String
```

So I change `time2` to datetime.

```
> time2.to_datetime.class
 => DateTime 
> time2.to_datetime
 => Thu, 23 Feb 2017 10:50:27 +0630
```

And try to compare those time again.

```
> time1 == time2.to_datetime
 => false 
> time1
 => Thu, 23 Feb 2017 10:50:27 +0630 
> time2.to_datetime
 => Thu, 23 Feb 2017 10:50:27 +0630
```

The result is false.

Comment: I can see mm-ms of date 1 difference to date 2

Comment: I was adding value of time1 to time2. So, I think, only the class/type is different.

Answer (score 1):

Time 1 is datetime object while time 2 is string type object
Here you have to convert `time2` to datetime

And to compare two date you will have to convert both in integer using following way

```
 »  time1.to_i == time2.to_datetime.to_i                                                                                                                                                         
 => true
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to compare two strings or two integers instead of two `DateTime` objects because `DateTime` holds information such as time zone etc.

```
time1.to_s == time2
#=> true
```

Comment: This is also right way, to compare two object, both have same datatype.

Answer (score 0):

False because we had different minutes:

```
> time1 == time2.to_datetime
 => false 
> time1
 => Thu, 23 Feb 2017 10:37:56 +0630 
> time2.to_datetime
 => Thu, 23 Feb 2017 10:26:18 +0630
```

`10:37:56 +0630` is greater than `10:26:18 +0630`

So, if you compare as:

```
time1 > time2.to_datetime
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> time1.to_i == time2.to_datetime.to_i
 => true
```

This works. But not an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
DateTime.strptime(time1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M") == DateTime.strptime(time2.to_datetime, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
=>> true
```

Comment: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of DateTime into String` Because `time1` is datetime object. not a string. And I also tried `> time1 == DateTime.strptime(time2, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")
 => false`